# Using return with a ternary operator is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I originally had something like:

```
<div class=""></div>

$(function () {
    $("div").on("click", function () {
        $(this).addClass(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass("")) {
                return "scale";
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And then tried to make it simpler, but am getting an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token return

```
<div class=""></div>

$(function () {
    $("div").on("click", function () {
        $(this).addClass(function () {
            $(this).hasClass("") ? return "scale" : return ""; 
        });
    });
 });
```

I tried wrapping the whole statement in parentheses and using one return value but I still receive the same error.

am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: The conditional operator is an *expression*, the return statement is, well, a statement. In general, statements cannot be contained in expressions, it's rather the other way round. Since  the structure of the return statement is `return <expression>;`, you can put any expression after the the `return` keyword, including the conditional operator.

Comment: @FelixKling: That makes perfect sense, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
$(function () {
    $("div").on("click", function () {
        $(this).addClass(function () {
            return $(this).hasClass("") ? "scale" : "";
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
$(function () {
    $("div").on("click", function () {
        $(this).addClass(function () {
            return $(this).hasClass("") ? "scale" : "";
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @user2930185 just corrected another error, it is `return $(this).hasClass("") ? "scale" : "";` not `return $(this).hasClass("") ? "scale" : return "";`